# Instrumentation tests not found in Android Project on Kotlin

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, automated-tests

There's problem with instrumentation tests in Android project: they're running when invoked from Project Structure window, but `No tests found` when they're running from editor's green arrow. I suppose that they're running as Unit Test.

Funny part is that Java project has no problems with that. And if I run Instrumented tests on OS Windows or MacOS - everything is okey, but not in Ubuntu.

Kotlin plugin version is `1.2.21`. Gradle version is `3.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution after multiple tries. I don't know what the exact problem is. Maybe it is the new version of Android Studio, or Kotlin support.

My Instrumentation tests were launched as Unit tests because Android Studio recognises them as Unit tests.

To resolve this issue, you just need to delete your Android Studio's [configuration folder](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html) and relaunch the IDE again.

Comment: Be careful of this. It's almost like re-installing Android Studio entirely. You're going to los all of your settings and preferences. Seems like an overkill solution.